# How do I make a website in WordPress nonresponsive?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a blog to build and I am using the "ample blog theme" in WordPress. The website should be non responsive. The mobile version should look the same as the desktop version. I have removed . It did not work. I have replaced the "content="width=device-width" to "content=width=1024". It did not work. I have replaced the media queries in the bootstrap.min.css to 200px. That did not work. I am asking what else to try. The theme I am using is "Ample Blog". I was told by the theme support to remove the bootstrap CSS, but when I did everything become stacked in desktop mode.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want this?

Comment: Bootstrap is a free and open-source CSS framework directed at responsive, mobile-first front-end web development. If you dont want responsiveness dont use framework ? But Bootstrap have solution to your problem - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the source code in the browser to see if the device width meta is being reinserted by a plugin via javascript or php method.

If yes, try disabling individual third party plugins and check each time.

Another option is to set the main wrapper width to an absolute width and use !important example

```css
.mainwrapper {width: 1200px !important; min-width: 1200px !important;}
```

Comment: yeah, it was a plugin issue. So I disable it.